# Is it possible to install PostgreSQL 9.6 (Beta) on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, postgresql

I'm using repository from [postgresql.org](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt) and trying to get PostgreSQL 9.6 (beta) for Ubuntu. Just in case, the repository is `http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/` references at https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/

```
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg main
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg-testing main
```

Running

> `sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.6`

It says

> Package postgresql-9.6 is not available, but is referred to by another
>   package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been
>   obsoleted, or is only available from another source
>
> E: Package 'postgresql-9.6' has no installation candidate

I also see that `postgresql-9.6` was removed from repository [here](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/?noppa=&page=2&type=ppas&vals=139) -

> 05-14 19:08 UTC   postgresql-9.6  trusty-pgdg main    base    *DELETED*
>   9.6~beta1-1.pgdg14.04+1

Also [here](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/postgresql/trusty-pgdg/main/base/postgresql-9.6):

> WARNING: the "postgresql-9.6" package was deleted from this repository

Is it currently not possible to get postgresql 9.6 using apt-get?

Answer (score 4):

According to the PostgreSQL Apt FAQ:
[I want to try the beta version of the next PostgreSQL release](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt/FAQ#I_want_to_try_the_beta_version_of_the_next_PostgreSQL_release):

> We ship packages for alpha and beta releases, but like in the previous
>   FAQ entry, we have only one version of libpq5 in the main archive
>   component. To use packages of postgresql-9.6, you need to add the 9.6
>   component to your /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list entry, so the 9.6
>   version of libpq5 will be available for installation:
>
> deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ jessie-pgdg main 9.6

So `9.6` being a component (in APT terminology), you don't want to use a testing distribution, but rather adapt the above to Ubuntu 14.04 as:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg main 9.6
```

After `sudo apt-get update` and before installing, you may check the details of the candidate package just to be sure:

```
$ apt-cache policy postgresql-9.6
postgresql-9.6:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 9.6~beta2-1.pgdg14.04+1
  Version table:
     9.6~beta2-1.pgdg14.04+1 0
        500 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg/9.6 amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Then `sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.6` should work fine.

The 9.6 beta may also coexist with non-beta versions such as 9.5 and previous versions.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add another repository path to add postgresql 9.6 to the available software installable by your package manager.

I found an official [Manual](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/) and [Download](https://www.postgresql.org/download/) Link on the postgresql page.
A list of official Repositories (including PostgreSQL 9.6 beta testing repo) is available [here](http://yum.postgresql.org/repopackages.php).

These Repos contain 9.6 and 9.6-testing packages:
http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/dists/trusty-pgdg/9.6/binary-amd64/Release

```
Archive: trusty-pgdg
Component: 9.6
Origin: apt.postgresql.org
Label: PostgreSQL for Debian/Ubuntu repository
Architecture: amd64
```

http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/dists/trusty-pgdg-testing/9.6/binary-amd64/Release

```
Archive: trusty-pgdg-testing
Component: 9.6
Origin: apt.postgresql.org
Label: PostgreSQL for Debian/Ubuntu repository
Architecture: amd64
NotAutomatic: yes
ButAutomaticUpgrades: yes
```

Comment: I already included `http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/` and it doesn't install 9.6 version for me. The `http://yum.postgresql.org/` link you referenced doesn't have Ubuntu versions